# e-cig on board 18 hour flight

Tags: air-travel, international-travel, regulations, smoking, e-cigarettes

Anyone know if I can bring my e-cig on an international flight to Australia?  If there is no "smoke" and only vapor what's to stop me from taking a drag while in the lavatory?  The smoke detector won't go off.  What if I exhale my vapor into my shirt sleve?

Comment: Welcome to travel.SE.  Where are you flying from? and What airline are you flying with?

Comment: Are you asking if you can break the law ?

Comment: Long story short.  Australian Civil Aviation Safety Authority leaves it up to the airlines.

Answer (score 4):

It depends on whom you're flying with.

Qantas, for example, [does not allow e-Cigarettes to be used on board](http://www.qantas.com.au/travel/airlines/dangerous-goods/global/en).

> e-Cigarettes
>
> The use of e-cigarettes is not permitted on any Qantas aircraft. If carried, they must only be packed in carry-on baggage, together with all spare batteries. Spare batteries must be individually protected so as to prevent short circuits using one of the following:
>
> in original retail packaging;
>
> taping over exposed terminals;
>
> placing each battery in a separate plastic bag or protective pouch.

Neither does [Emirates](http://www.emirates.com/english/help/FAQDetails.aspx?faqId=595213).  Other airlines like Malaysian or Air New Zealand don't have documented policies.  Your best bet is to ring whatever airline you're travelling with and check, but expect to be denied.

Comment: For what it's worth neither does KLM. As to your other question -- would I caught? Well, probably not, but if you do the ramifications (fines, potentially banned from flying, etc) are really not worth it. I'd take some nicotine gum if it's really worrying you.